# Possible Conference Speaking Sponsorships -- 2011

Tags: discussion

We're evaluating the feasibility of **sponsoring a member of the electronics design community to speak at a conference in 2011**.

Speaking is a relatively big "ask", so this needs to be planned many months in advance. Let's get started!

We'd like the community to establish **where** ...

> What relevant electronics design conferences are coming up in 2011 that have open speaker slots or calls for papers?

... and then **who**.

> Which members of the community are strongly interested in being sponsored by Stack Exchange, Inc to speak at one of the above conferences in 2011?

To be clear, the speaker is free talk about anything he or she wants so long as it would be roughly on topic for this site -- with a quick acknowledgement of support from Stack Exchange and a mention of the community here.

Comment: Wonderful initiative

Comment: I think the questions might be asked in the opposite order, Find the members of the community that are interested in speaking, then finding out what conferences they are interested in. In our community the number of conferences is very large and can have much variation while only a select number of people will be interested in speaking and will only be qualified to speak at a select number of conferences.

Comment: Some suggestions: @kortuk, @chrisgammell, @tronixstuff

Comment: I hadn't seen this before and notice it was posted 10 months ago before I ever heard of Stack Exchange.  What's the status of this initiative.  Is this something you are still persuing?  And what does "sponsor" mean?  Pay travel and expenses?  I like speaking and have done so a number of times at different conferences, but I'd need a lot more information to know if this is something I'm interested in.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Check out [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/supporting-community-conferences/) for details. We evaluate these sponsorships on a case by case basis, but the post will explain roughly what's on the table and how to get started.

Answer (score 4):

So me and Max (Kortuk) have been talking about this on and off for a while now, namely since this thread had started. I would definitely consider representing Electronics Stack Exchange, assuming the group would want me representing it. I have not been as active on the boards recently, so I understand if people might not be in favor of this. However, I'm a still a big fan of the site and watch threads every once in a while.

The conference I had suggested was the [Asilomar Microcomputing Workshop](http://www.amw.org/) in April. If I attended, I'd likely give a talk about online communication regardless, since that's what I feel I could talk about with the most confidence to a group with so much experience in electronics (I'd mention blogging and my radio show and the like). I think there would be a lot of opportunity to try and pull some of them into the site and having their experience added to the group could be a very positive thing.

So, what does everyone think? Is this still a priority for the group?

Comment: I'll vote for ya, I think you'd make a great representative for the community. I also think it's a fantastic way to spread word about the E Stack and get more people involved +1

Answer (score 1):

So normally I wouldn't ask again (dual answers and all), but I just received information about the deadlines for the Asilomar Micro Workshop (see above). If this is something Electronics SE wants me to do, I'm willing. If not, I'll drop it.

Comment: Shooting you an email, but just putting a public artifact here that we've seen this and are investigating the possibility. (: